# Azure Event Hub: every other connection attempt fails

Tags: azureservicebus

We have Azure 4 subscriptions containing one Event Hub instance each. One of the instances is not responsive, from our application logs:

```
Jan 05 10:53:10 ERROR CheckFacade - Azure event hub connection failed. EndPoint: sb://xxxx.servicebus.windows.net/, ...
Jan 05 10:53:10 System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
Jan 05 10:53:10     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Jan 05 10:53:10     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Jan 05 10:53:10     at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpEventHubClient.<CreateConnectionAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
...
```

1 out 2 times connection attempt fails. Is there any way to see Event Hub logs to tackle this issue?

Note: Azure support recommended to ask this question here.